# Distribution of app for perticular users

Tags: android

I need to upload my app on Google play but i want it to be shown to only few people (my friends). I don't want anyone else to see it download that app. Is this possible?

Comment: If you are sharing with only friends, host your app on your own web space.  You do not have to distribute via Google.

Comment: But is there any way of doing what i m asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deploy to alpha or beta channel and setup closed group that have access - https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en